# Comparing Numpy dtypes in sets vs tuples?

Tags: python, numpy

So, I happened upon this strange issue where seeing if a set contains a Numpy dtype object vs. seeing if a tuple contains one gives different results:

```
In [1]: x = np.zeros(8)

In [2]: x.dtype
Out[2]: dtype('float64')

In [3]: x.dtype in (np.float32, np.float64)
Out[3]: True

In [4]: x.dtype in {np.float32, np.float64}
Out[4]: False
```

Why does this happen? What's preventing `set().__contains__()` from returning `True` when looking at `numpy.dtype` objects?

Comment: Interesting.. `x.dtype in {np.float32, np.float64, np.dtype('float64')}` this is working.. But I also wonder why this is happeneing..

Comment: I suspect the `set` is using a `is` test, while tuple (or list) uses a looser `==` test.  `float64` is actually a function (type is `type`).  `np.dtype('float64')` is a `dtype` object.

Comment: Yeah looks like that,  
For `x = 1.0`  
`print (type(x) in {npa.float32, np.float64})`  
`print(isinstance(1.0, (np.float64,np.float32)))`  
This returns False While,  
`print(type(x) in {float, np.float32, np.float64})`  
`print(isinstance(1.0, (float, np.float32, np.float64)))`  
This returns True.

Comment: @sharathnatraj, he is testing `dtype` of an array, not the `type` of Python `float`.

Comment: Ofcourse.. I just used python 'float' as example for my testing. The behaviour is same for 'dtype' of 'numpy' array also. This was just to see set is using a 'isinstance()' type of test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking membership in a set uses `__hash__()` instead of `__eq__()`. In this case, it simply turns out that the objects are equal to each other but generate different hashes:

```
In [1]: np.float64 == np.dtype(np.float64)
Out[1]: True

In [2]: hash(np.float64)
Out[2]: 8793996338852

In [3]: hash(np.dtype(np.float64))
Out[3]: -7365930899603730638
```